# MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr C++ exceptions

Tags: c++, com

I noticed on the [MSDN website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765513(v=vs.85).aspx) that it used a catch all exception handler. I.e.:

```
try {
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr docPtr;
    MSXML2::IXMLDOMNodePtr DOMNodePtr;

    // init
    TESTHR(CoInitialize(NULL)); 
    TESTHR(docPtr.CreateInstance("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0"));

    VARIANT vtTemp;

    vtTemp.vt=VT_I2;
    vtTemp.iVal = 1; //NODE_ELEMENT
    // load a document
    _variant_t varXml("c:\\Temp\\books.xml");
    _variant_t varOut((bool)TRUE);
    varOut = docPtr->load(varXml);
    if ((bool)varOut == FALSE)
        throw(0);
    MessageBox(NULL, _bstr_t(docPtr->xml), _T("Original Document"), MB_OK);
    DOMNodePtr = docPtr->createNode(vtTemp, "VIDEOS", "");
    docPtr->documentElement->appendChild(DOMNodePtr);
    MessageBox(NULL, _bstr_t(docPtr->xml), _T("New Document"), MB_OK);

} catch(...)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, _T("Exception occurred"), _T("Error"), MB_OK);
}
```

Now my question is, does the function calls to the `MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr` object throw any exceptions?  I wasn't aware that a COM object could throw a C++ exception due to the COM boundary can interface with any language.

If it is just to catch the `throw(0)`, then why not catch on an `int`?  I know a little theory on COM but my knowledge is a little limited.

Comment: By design, do **not** catch(...), you'll have no idea what went wrong.  Use `catch (_com_error& ex)` instead.

Comment: COM objects can't throw exceptions. But `IXMLDOMDocumentPtr` is not a COM object - it's a smart pointer class (based on [`_com_ptr_t`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/417w8b3b.aspx) template) wrapping a raw COM interface pointer. When you call a method on this class, it calls a method on the acttual COM interface, then inspects the returned `HRESULT` and, if it indicates failure, throws `_com_error`